# Confused on passing parameter to MVC Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I inherited an MVC site and was asked to combine two pages into one. Since both Views have their own View Model, I thought instead of pushing the two VMs together that I could use a Partial View to display, in this case, the Clock Group in a View called Clock_Detail. However, I need to get the GroupId to populate the data for the Clock Group.

So, having rarely used Partial Views I’m confused on how to get this to work. 
I created a new View called `_ClockGroup.cshtml` and just copied and pasted some basic code from the other page just to see if I could get anything to display.

In my ClockDetail controller I added the following.

```
public PartialViewResult ClockGroup(int groupId)
{
    ClockGroupViewModel vm = DAL.GetClockGroupDetail(groupId);
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

Here is _ClockGroup.cshtml

```
@model site.Models.ViewModels.ClockGroupViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GroupName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

This is from the clock_detail.cshtml view. It uses the following Model and then I added the Partial to this view.

```
@model site.Models.ViewModels.ClockDetailViewModel

@Html.Partial("_ClockGroup")
```

Of course I get an error that the model passed a dictionary type `“site.Models.ViewModels.ClockDetailViewModel”` but the dictionary requires a model item of time `“site.Models.ViewModels.ClockGroupViewModel"`.

Will I need to go ahead and combine the two ViewModels together and just use the single ViewModel?

Comment: By the way you're writing code in your partials, you should probably look at using [Templates instead](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html).  Templates are advantageous because they read much better and the convention for calling them makes them easier to diagnose.  It's rare for me to use partials.

Comment: I'll take a look at Templates. I'm always open to trying something if it helps the maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not specify an object as the second parameter:

```
@Html.Partial("_ClockGroup")
```

It automatically passes the current model which is of type `ClockDetailViewModel`

Your partial requires type `ClockGroupViewModel`

The fix would be when you call the partial to pass in the `ClockGroupViewModel` property of your `ClockDetailViewModel` object:

```
@Html.Partial("_ClockGroup", Model.ClockGroupViewModelProperty)
```

If your `ClockDetailViewModel` class does not have a `ClockGroupViewModel` property, you will need to add that to your ViewModel and populate the data.

Comment: I read where not passing a model would pass the current model and figured that's part of the issue. However, I couldn't figure out how I pass the ClockGroupViewModel to the partial. My ClockDetailViewModel does not have a ClockGroupViewModel property. I guess I'll need to look into what I need to do to get that done. Thanks...

Comment: I feel like it's double dipping on database trips but at least it looks like that will work without having to re-write a bunch of code.

Comment: ...I thought we were talking about view models here?  View models are just containers of data that a view is dependent on.  Your view models should rarely be 1 to 1 representations of your database models.

Comment: I am using VMs but I added the ClockGroupVM as a property to the ClockDetailVM. The ClockGroupVM has it's own DB call to get the detail and then the ClockGroup calls the DB again to populate it. Again, not a huge deal at the moment but I'll have to look and see if I can maybe get all the data in one call. It works and is keeping me from having to significantly re-write the VM and pages and that is what I was looking for.